# do a web Calendar in java

Tags: java, interface, scheduler, zk, schedule

I am trying do a calendar and  i am working with ZK framework.

The problem is that i have the CE version, ZK CE that is the free version, and i like do something like that:

http://www.zkoss.org/zkdemo/application/zk_calendar

I like do it with zk or with anything (faces), but i do not found how can i do it, if somebody can give me guidance.

The CE version does not include the calendar option, but i suppose that there is a way to do it, if somebody can help me.

Thanks

Comment: http://www.7thweb.net/wicket-jquery-ui/calendar/ExtendedCalendarPage;jsessionid=1CB2BF77B05C719E6736075C5F542836?0 . This is apache wicket + jquery. See it thats fine

Answer (score 0):

Its obvious if you are not using `ZK EE` you will get less features of ZK Framework if you want to create a Calendar component you have do it by your self . You have to use [Jquery](http://designm.ag/resources/15-useful-jquery-calendar-and-date-picker-plugins/) API for this and write the `Java` classes and other stuffs .